# Тип данных шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Дан шаблон класса для хранения списка элементов типа T. Какие типы данных нельзя использовать в качестве T?

```
template <typename T> class List {
  private:
    struct element {
        T data;
        element *next;
    };
    element *head;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Инстанцирование или определение вы имеете в ввиду? Похоже что определение. Параметрами шаблонов могут быть параметры типы, параметры встроенные типы и параметры шаблонов. Предыдущий параметр может быть использован для определения последующих параметров.

Comment: `void` подойдёт?

Answer (score 5):

В таком виде нельзя в качестве типа использовать ссылки. Их нужно сразу инициировать при создании, а в случае членов класса это можно сделать только в списке инициализации в конструкторе.

Благодаря уточнению [[@Котик_хочет_кушать](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) добавляю, что это ограничение свойственно для С++2003. В С++11 можно с помощью initializer-clause
.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а собственно, почему? В какой момент рухнет?

Comment: @avp Не скомпилится шаблон.

Comment: Почему только в конструкторе? Структуру можно инициализировать при объявлении переменной через = { ... }

Comment: @sercxjo Такой способ инициализации применим только для `POD` типов данных, а структура, содержащая нестатический член `reference` типа [не является `POD`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb982918)

Comment: Наверное, @mikillskegg и имел ввиду ссылки-referenc'ы. С простыми указателями ответ не вяжется.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать ну это microsoft так считает, есть ещё полно компиляторов, в gcc можно

Comment: Согласно стандарту в С++ нельзя инициировать элементы структуры при их создании. В отличии от С99. Если какой-то компилятор это поддерживает, то в качестве расширения. gcc, непример, не поддерживает.

@mega, естественно, reference. Путать их с простыми указателями - грубейшая ошибка.

Comment: @mikillskegg А как быть вот с этим?

> §8.5.1/2: When **an aggregate** is initialized the initializer can contain an *initializer-clause* consisting of a **brace-enclosed,** comma-separated list of initializer-clauses for the members of the aggregate, written in increasing subscript or member order. If the aggregate contains subaggregates, this rule applies recursively to the members of the subaggregate.

Comment: >Путать их с простыми указателями - грубейшая ошибка.

@mikillskegg, вот Вы не поверите, здесь по крайней мере 2 человека в Вашем ответе их спутало. За себя могу сказать, что опыт программирования у меня довольно богатый, наукой не обижен, гранит грызу периодически, не кашляю. Однако термин "reference" распознал только по контексту Вашего ответа, причем не сразу. А в быту спокойно называю ссылками и обычные указатели. Грубейшей ошибкой будет путать их суть и возможности, но ни как не перевод. Поэтому, в таком контексте, чтобы Вас правильно понимали, **referenc'ы** все же следует выделять явно

Comment: А я и в быту стараюсь их не спутывать.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, ОК, это в С++11. В С++2003 такого не было. Кстати, gcc компилирует такой инициализатор, но выдает warning. А icpc 12 не компилирует даже с -std=c++0x. Спасибо за информацию, не знал об этой фиче С++11.

Comment: >А я и в быту стараюсь их не спутывать.

Одиноко Вам, наверное :D

Comment: @mega, тяжело, наверное, профессионалу работать в обществе непрофессионалов (хотя я и сам далеко не профессионал ))))  )

Comment: Профессионал - это такая точка невозврата, после которой развиваться уже не нужно. Она достижима только на каком-то срезе времен/сфер влияния/поколений и т.п. До конца света еще есть пара дней, давайте не будем спешить. :))

Answer (score 3):

> Какие типы данных нельзя использовать в качестве T

Здесь нельзя использовать абстрактные типы данных, например: интерфейсы. И `void` - естественно. Да и компилятор, скорее всего, сразу об этом скажет.

К чему этот вопрос? Вроде все очевидно.

Comment: void можно, у меня работает

Comment: кроме того, параметром шаблона может, например, число. оно к примеру тоже не подходит.

Comment: >void можно, у меня работает

У Вас скомпилировался класс с членом

 void data;
? Оригинально!

>параметром шаблона может, например, число. оно к примеру тоже не подходит.

Число - конечно подойдет, но оно - **не тип данных**

Comment: @mega, что Вы имеете в виду под термином "интерфейс"? Класс со всеми абсолютно виртуальными членами?

Comment: Да, под интерфейсом я подразумеваю класс без данных, с абстрактными методами.

Comment: Проверил с void на gcc 4.6.3: переменная List<void> вроде как объявляется, но конструктор не вызывается, т.е. он её оптимизирует и вырезает, но если я далее пытаюсь её использовать - тогда выдаёт ошибку компиляции

Comment: Шаблоны - они такие :), компилируются по факту, т.е. в данном случае, сама специализация List<void> скомпилирована не была. А когда компилируется, соответственно, выдает красочную ошибку. В случае с int&, Вы тоже хитрите, т.к. не используете методы, которые бы вызывали конструктор по-умолчанию `element`, реакция на который была бы аналогична.

Comment: Да, я инициализирую структуру другим способом